# Why is my Code Block Instance Variable not Initializing and printing out a "NSGlobalBlock"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, spritebuilder

I am using sprite builder and Xcode.

Does anyone see where I am going wrong with my code block "whereToNext" property? Im trying to use it to navigate between scenes but for some reason it isn't going into the initialization code in -(void)patterns even though it is going into the patterns method. Since it never goes into the whereToNext=^{} code, when i call it in the next() method nothing happens. (The next method is called via a code connection to a button in sprite builder.)

As a second question concerning CCTextField:
I placed two CCTextField node in my TrialCustomization.cbb (which has the ExperimentSelection custom class code connection) on sprite builder and then created two doc root var code connection "_blocks" and "_trials" then created a variable in the corresponding class with the same name CCTextField *_blocks; and the same for _trials but when i give that text field input it doesn't save it into the variables i saved them into in their corresponding methods.

```
#import "CCNode.h"
@interface ExperimentSelection : CCNode
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^whereToNext)(void);
@property CCTextField* _trials;
@property CCTextField* _blocks;

extern int trials;
extern int blocks;

-(void)patterns;

-(void)setTrialandBlock;
@end


@implementation ExperimentSelection

@synthesize whereToNext;
@synthesize  _blocks;
@synthesize  _trials;

-(void)patterns{
    whereToNext=^{
        CCScene *patternsSelection = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"PatternsSelection"];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:patternsSelection];
        NSLog(@"Why is this code not being executed??");
   };

    NSLog(@"whereToNext: %@", whereToNext);
    [self setTrialandBlock];
}

-(void)_trials:(CCTextField*)trialsNum{
   trials=[trialsNum.string intValue];
 }

-(void)_blocks:(CCTextField*)blocksNum{
    blocks=[blocksNum.string intValue];
 }

-(void)setTrialandBlock{

    CCScene *customizeExperiment = [CCBReader      loadAsScene:@"TrialCustomization"];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:customizeExperiment];

    NSLog(@"blocks: %i, trials: %i",blocks, trials);
}

-(void)next{
    NSLog(@"wherearewegoingnext: %@, blocks: %i, trials: %i",whereToNext, blocks, trials);
    whereToNext();
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure what `-(void)patterns` was called?

If YES, try change

`void(^whereToNext)(void);`

to

`@property(nonatomic, copy) void(^whereToNext)(void);`

**UPD**

I think there is no problem with creation of block or with execution of the block. I think there is some logic problem in the code. May be exist some parent or child class that overload "patterns" method. You can add a break point to property whereToNext and view then this property is changed.

Comment: In the interface class?

Comment: In the interface or in the category.  For private methods I use categories. Are you using ARC?

Comment: this still isn't working. As soon as i declare it in the patterns method I am printing out an NSLog(@"WhereToNext: %@" , whereToNext). And i am still getting <_NSGlobalBlock__: 0x28da10> which I'm assuming is just an address instead of the content that I wanted to fill it with

Comment: O, may be I do not understand, are you trying print of the content of block? If YES, then you can't create this, because block it is a pointer to C structure (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html). Block it is not string of some script. You can only  check it to nil (if(whereToNext){ <smth>})

Comment: oh okay. But when I am calling whereToNext() the code inside of the code block isn't being executed and I even added a print statement within the     whereToNext=^{
        CCScene *patternsSelection = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"PatternsSelection"];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:patternsSelection];
        NSLog(@"HELLO");
    };  and i am never seeing this. I don't know why the code inside the brackets is never being reached?

Comment: Can you share test project on GitHub? Without Cocos.